# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.1

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I add firebase cloud messaging depencency implementation **'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.1'** I get a error :  **ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.1**

My Depencency here:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'me.spark:submitbutton:1.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

How I can solved it? Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use use very old Firebase client libraries.  The latest versions are listed in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  You should make sure to use all the most recent versions together.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

You should also no longer use firebase-core.  If you are trying to use Analytics, do this instead:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the latest Firebase Messaging. Refer to this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

> Cloud Messaging   com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
```

Make sure to use the latest ver lib.

Alternatively, you can press every lib there ALT + Enter, and it will display if you want to use update new version