# how do I access firebase database for login activity in android studio

Tags: android, firebase

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.2.2

I get an error message like this if I try to add implementation of firebase database and sync it.
and I don't have firebase core -implementation instead I have firebase analytics-implementation.
can anyone help me to sync firebase database

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161586/error-failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-messaging16-0-1), hope it helps you

Comment: Have you test my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to your root level `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And in top level gradle file use the latest version of google play services

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Add the dependency for the Realtime Database Android library to your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually `app/build.gradle`):

- For **Java** : `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'`
- For **Kotlin** : `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.3.0'`

Next Steps are you may got to your Firebase Console open project & [Create a Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#create_a_database) & [Configure Real time data base rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#configure) .